# Error when save data in CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to save the data in CoreData and have got an error.

**NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'File''**

Here is code:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)listFileAtPath:(NSString *)path
{
    NSMutableArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:NULL];
    return directoryContent;
}
-(void)FileData
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    File *myMO = (File*) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"File" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [myMO setValue:[self listFileAtPath:documentsDirectory] forKey:@"filename"];
}
```

Why did not he see my entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[self managedObjectContext]` is returning `nil` according to the error message, look into this method to verify it is returning a proper `NSMangedObjectContext`

Comment: It's impossible to tell, you will need to post your implementation of `[self managedObjectContext]`